# Excel Impossible to set ColumnWidth

Tags: excel, vb.net, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm working on a PowerPoint add-in where I need to load a table as an OLE object (`slide.Shapes.AddOLEObject(...., "Excel.Sheet")`).
My table is coming from an external source and is a JSON.

In the following code I create the table from the JSON. Resizing rows works but resizing the columns fires an exception on the last line:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : 'Impossible de définir la propriété ColumnWidth de la classe Range.'

```vb
Public Sub buildOLEObject(oleObject As Object, oleData As JSONReqFormats.ExcelJSONContent)
    Dim nbColumns = oleData.cells.GetLength(1)
    Dim nbRows = oleData.cells.GetLength(0)
    Dim colIndex = 1
    Dim rowsIndex = 1
    While rowsIndex <= nbRows
        While colIndex <= nbColumns
            Dim jsonCell = oleData.cells(rowsIndex - 1, colIndex - 1)
            Dim cell = oleObject.Cells(rowsIndex, colIndex)
            cell.EntireRow.RowHeight = jsonCell.height
            cell.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = jsonCell.width
```

Any idea how to resize columns?

Comment: I don't know why the post is marked as duplicate of a question that is not relevant

Comment: Because I suggested that it is relevant, and you [agreed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjwgQ.png) by pressing the big blue button.

Comment: @GSerg classic!

Comment: This question is now in the "Reopen Votes" review queue. If you "agreed" to the duplicate in error, then you should explain why, in a comment. (I seldom reopen a question that has been closed by the OP agreeing with a duplicate suggestion; other reviewers likely have similar behaviour.)

Comment: @AdrianMole https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69358236/impossible-to-set-columnwidth-on-class-range#comment122594798_69358236